# How to set image in custom rounded corner image view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, uiimageview, android-camera

hello am working in android camera application i want to show clicked image in rounded corner image view how can i implement these.i posted a image given below .Please assist me ?

Imageview is look like this

[image: one]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the custom ImageView class below.

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {
    private Path mMaskPath;
    private Paint mMaskPaint    = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private int mCornerRadius   = 10;

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        init(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        ViewCompat.setLayerType(this, ViewCompat.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        mMaskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        mMaskPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

        mCornerRadius = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_border_curvature);
    }

    /**
     * Set the corner radius to use for the RoundedRectangle.
     */
    public void setCornerRadius(int cornerRadius) {
        mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;
        generateMaskPath(getWidth(), getHeight());
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);

        if (w != oldW || h != oldH) {
            generateMaskPath(w, h);
        }
    }

    private void generateMaskPath(int w, int h) {
        mMaskPath = new Path();
        mMaskPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(0,0,w,h), mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
        mMaskPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(canvas.isOpaque()) { // If canvas is opaque, make it transparent
            canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), 255, Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if(mMaskPath != null) {
            canvas.drawPath(mMaskPath, mMaskPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Use this ImageView inside your xml.

Comment: thanks Febi how can i use in xml can you please assist me

Comment: <your.package.name.RoundedImageView
            android:layout_width="photo_size"
            android:layout_height="photo_size"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

Comment: and how can i set dimension that you mention in your code

Comment: Either you can provide wrap_content as both height and width or provide a dp value. For eg; android:layout_width="60dp"

Comment: (R.dimen.image_border_curvature) what is image_border_curvature

Comment: Provide a corner radius your need inside dimens.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

I use this library https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView more then two years and im very pleased of it. You just need to add this lines in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
}
```

and define your `RoundedImageView` widget like this

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/photo1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
        app:riv_border_width="2dip"
        app:riv_border_color="#333333"
        app:riv_mutate_background="true"
        app:riv_tile_mode="repeat"
        app:riv_oval="true" />
```

and voala you are ready!

Hope to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your ImageView inside a CardView. You can use app:cardCornerRadius to set corner radius. as simple as that

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgUserHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/photo"/>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I'm using this work around and everything seems fine LOL

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying it on your own, use some libraries like [this](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) for your purpose. It has diffrent shapes and works well.

In dependency of `build.gradle` of app moudle add this line:

```
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
```

sync gradle and now your app has accsess to the library. Now use below code for adding it to you layout:

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.BubbleImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/neo"
app:siArrowPosition="right"
app:siSquare="true"/>
```

follow the library page for more customization.

Comment: but i dont know how to import and use liberary

Comment: ok i compile it in my gradle but it show error in gradle wraper file

Comment: Error:(8, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>
The project 'opencamera-code-aeb04f4a82252e9f6d756e4409c9f55b9ce42ac0' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below dependency in the gradle and use it in the xml as follows

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/pad_120dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/pad_120dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_profile" />
```